# Editable JComboBox gives error: <identifier> expected and illegal start of type

Tags: java, jcombobox

I am trying to create and Editable JComboBox to allow the user to type the name of the song to purchase. However when I set tunes.setEditable(true); I get an error... any help will be appreciated!

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class JTunes2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener
    {
       int songNum,songPrice;
       int[] songAmount = {2,5,8,1,4,7,12,10,11,3,6,9};

       String result;

       JComboBox tunes = new JComboBox();

       // set as editable 
       tunes.setEditable(true);

       JLabel labelTunes = new JLabel("Song List");
       JLabel outputs = new JLabel();

       FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();

    public JTunes2()
    {
       super("Song Selector");
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(layout);

      // add song names to combo box and register an item listener.

       tunes.addItem("Song1");
       tunes.addItem("Song2");
       tunes.addItem("Song3");
       tunes.addItem("Song4");
       tunes.addItem("Song5");
       tunes.addItem("Song6");
       tunes.addItem("Song7");
       tunes.addItem("Song8");
       tunes.addItem("Song9");
       tunes.addItem("Song10");
       tunes.addItem("Song11");
       tunes.addItem("Song12");
       tunes.addItemListener(this);


       panel.add(labelTunes);
       panel.add(tunes);

       panel.add(outputs);

     //add panel to the frame
       setContentPane(panel);


    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
      //create source object
      Object source = e.getSource();

      //check the type size
      if(source == tunes)
      {
         songNum = tunes.getSelectedIndex();
         songPrice = songAmount[songNum];
         result = "Total Price $" + songPrice;

         //Display result
         outputs.setText(result);
      }


   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         // create class object
         JTunes frame = new JTunes();
         frame.setSize(250, 180);
         frame.setVisible(true);   
      }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Java requires that you setup JComponents in the constructor. In order for your code to work, you need to call on setEditable(true) in the constructor, which means that you just need to move tunes.setEditable(true); to the constructor.

Tip: always allocate memory for JComponents in the constructor (you want to draw the components as soon as you create the Jframe). You can have a reference to the JComboBox at the class level.

Here is another version of your code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class JTunes2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
   int songNum,songPrice;
   int[] songAmount = {2,5,8,1,4,7,12,10,11,3,6,9};

   String result;

   JComboBox tunes;



   JLabel labelTunes = new JLabel("Song List");
   JLabel outputs = new JLabel();

   FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();

public JTunes2()
{
   super("Song Selector");
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setLayout(layout);

   tunes = new JComboBox();
   // set as editable 
   tunes.setEditable(true);

  // add song names to combo box and register an item listener.

   tunes.addItem("Song1");
   tunes.addItem("Song2");
   tunes.addItem("Song3");
   tunes.addItem("Song4");
   tunes.addItem("Song5");
   tunes.addItem("Song6");
   tunes.addItem("Song7");
   tunes.addItem("Song8");
   tunes.addItem("Song9");
   tunes.addItem("Song10");
   tunes.addItem("Song11");
   tunes.addItem("Song12");
   tunes.addItemListener(this);


   panel.add(labelTunes);
   panel.add(tunes);

   panel.add(outputs);

 //add panel to the frame
   setContentPane(panel);


}


public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
  //create source object
  Object source = e.getSource();

  //check the type size
  if(source == tunes)
  {
     songNum = tunes.getSelectedIndex();
     songPrice = songAmount[songNum];
     result = "Total Price $" + songPrice;

     //Display result
     outputs.setText(result);
  }


}
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     // create class object
     JTunes2 frame = new JTunes2();
     frame.setSize(250, 180);
     frame.setVisible(true);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the `tunes.setEditable(true)` at the class level, instead of at the method level. No statements allowed at the class level!

Here's a fixed version: I renamed JTunes2 to JTunes to fix the compilation errors, and moved the `setEditable` to the constructor. Also I fixed the indentation - this makes it harder to make this mistake:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class JTunes extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
    int songNum,songPrice;
    int[] songAmount = {2,5,8,1,4,7,12,10,11,3,6,9};

    String result;

    JComboBox tunes = new JComboBox();

    JLabel labelTunes = new JLabel("Song List");
    JLabel outputs = new JLabel();

    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();

    public JTunes()
    {
        super("Song Selector");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        tunes.setEditable(true);

        // add song names to combo box and register an item listener.

        tunes.addItem("Song1");
        tunes.addItem("Song2");
        tunes.addItem("Song3");
        tunes.addItem("Song4");
        tunes.addItem("Song5");
        tunes.addItem("Song6");
        tunes.addItem("Song7");
        tunes.addItem("Song8");
        tunes.addItem("Song9");
        tunes.addItem("Song10");
        tunes.addItem("Song11");
        tunes.addItem("Song12");
        tunes.addItemListener(this);


        panel.add(labelTunes);
        panel.add(tunes);

        panel.add(outputs);

        //add panel to the frame
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        //create source object
        Object source = e.getSource();

        //check the type size
        if(source == tunes)
        {
            songNum = tunes.getSelectedIndex();
            songPrice = songAmount[songNum];
            result = "Total Price $" + songPrice;

            //Display result
            outputs.setText(result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create class object
        JTunes frame = new JTunes();
        frame.setSize(250, 180);
        frame.setVisible(true);   
    }
}
```